# Is Donut Caching working properly with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

And by donut caching, I'm refering to [Scott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx) which is awesome.

Does anyone know if that works properly?

Comment: That's a great link! Donut caching, when using the WebFormViewEngine also works with the declarative control too.

Comment: Yeah. I also sent an email to Mr. Guthrie to see if he had anything planned about that. He's still the Overlord of MVC after all. :)

Comment: Yes, you can donut cache by following the steps in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: Phil, AFAIK this is no longer correct

Comment: Can you please Phil let us know if your article work on asp.net mvc 3?

Answer (score 10):

Note that this technique no longer works as of MVC 2.0. Which sucks.

Comment: Care to expand on that thought?

Comment: Sure. It just doesn't work any more, the substitution only gets called once and then gets cached along with the rest of the page so whatever the first value of your substitution function is will be hard coded into your cached page. Apparently it's the result of a change in the page rendering mechanism in MVC2 (and 3 as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 1):

Cross-post from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685906/is-donut-caching-available-in-asp-net-mvc-3/6994582#6994582):

Donut Caching (yes, the real thing) is available as part of my 'speed-lib' for MVC: [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth). Works in both ASP.NET MVC 2 and MVC 3.

Docs are at [the wiki](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/wiki/Server-side-caching), and examples are in the [Mvc3.Demo](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/blob/master/Mvc3.Demo/Views/Home/OutputCaching.cshtml) folder

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: I've been using it and I really like Moth. @Jan: I think there's an issue where the filter modifies the headers after the response has been sent (on a redirect)... not sure, however; still investigating.

Comment: Hi, can you create an issue on the [Issues page](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/issues)?